# How can I change the class of HTML elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a cms theme, it has some customization features which I want to show on live demo. Basically I want to add Javascript style switchers or modifier. I want users to select some value from checkbox or select tags and the selected value should reflect on html element. for example,

my page container is

```
<div id="container"> <!--PAGE GOES HERE --> </div>
```

if users click on 'color scheme blue' on selecting this, I want my container to have the class 'blue_theme' added

```
<div id="container" class="blue_theme" > <!--PAGE GOES HERE --> </div>
```

Also, is it possible to directly change css property like this

```
/* Base property */
#container{
background:red;
}
```

if users click on 'color scheme blue' on selecting this, I want to make my container to be

```
/* Base property */
#container{
background:blue;
}
```

Comment: See my answer below with a demo, hope it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS also. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="color" class="red"/> Red
<input type="radio" name="color" class="blue" /> Blue
<div id="container" for>
    choose theme:
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.red:checked ~ #container { background: red}
.blue:checked ~ #container  { background: blue }
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/wd6Cr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#container").attr('class','custom_class_added');
})
```

You could use addClass() and removeClass() as well, depending on your function

Comment: Thanks. I am a jquery newbie. Can you please elaborate more how to implement this on my index.html?

Comment: You should wrap this code within HTML script tags and then wrap it on jQuery on dom ready like this : $(document).ready(function() { /*You Code goes here*/ }); to make sure that every element on the page is ready before applying the jQuery. Check out this : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Set a class instead of changing the ID of the `<div>`. Especially since space is not allowed in a ID name.

HTML (on change state)

```
<div id="container" class="custom_class_added">
```

CSS

```
#container.custom_class_added{
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding classes, [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('#container').addClass('custom_class_added');
```

For changing css, [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('#container').css('color', 'blue');
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a jquery newbie. Can you please elaborate more how to implement this on my index.html?

Comment: Indeed! But you should provide more code, we don't know how your checkboxes or select tags look like

Answer (score 0):

use `$('#container).css({'background-color' : 'blue'});` in your onchange events. that should work for the css style part.
as for the part where you want to add a class to your tag, use `$('#container).attr('class', 'custom_class_added');`, which will add the class attribute to your tag.

Using this code for form elements like selectboxes would go as followed:

```
<select id="mySelectBox">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mySelectBox").change(function(){
            $("#theElementYouWant").css({"background-color" : $("#mySelectBox").val()});
        });
    });
</script>
```

To use the `$('#container).attr('class', 'custom_class_added');` code, you could place it anywhere between your `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks. I am a jquery newbie. Can you please elaborate more how to implement this on my index.html?

Answer (score 0):

## Are you trying something like this:

### Solution 1:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    choose theme:
    <input type="radio" name="radio-theme" data-color="red" /> Red
    <input type="radio" name="radio-theme" data-color="blue" /> Blue
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#container").find("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
    var dataTheme = $(this).data("color");
    $("#container").removeAttr("class");
    $("#container").addClass(dataTheme);   
});​
```

### [DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/wd6Cr/)

### Solution 2:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    choose theme:
    <input type="checkbox" name="radio-theme" data-color="red" /> Red
    <input type="checkbox" name="radio-theme" data-color="blue" /> Blue
</div>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#container").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){    
    var dataTheme = $(this).data("color");    
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {        
        $("#container").removeAttr("class");
        $("#container").addClass(dataTheme);         
    } else {
        $("#container").removeAttr("class"); 
    }  
});​
```

### [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/pDkAX/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add a style to it with jQuery, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$('#container').css({
    "background-color" : "blue",
    "color" : "red"
});
```

Or, you can add a class to it when the user clicks a button:

```
<label for="blue_theme">Blue</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="blue_theme"/>
<div id="container"></div>​

$("#blue_theme").click(function() {
    $("#container").attr('class', 'blue_theme');
})​
```

ex.) http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/jp8UL/

Also, you should note that you might want to set a cookie if you want the style to stick on page load. I'd take a look at [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ID's and your function and HTML could look like this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="changer">
  <li class="blue">Blue color</li>
  <li class="red">Red color</li>
</ul>
<div id="container"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var $container = $('#container');
$('#changer').on('click', 'li', function(){

  var $this = $(this),
      $color = $this.attr('class');

  $container.removeClass().addClass($color);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this : http://jsbin.com/EKEYOfEl/4/

**HTML** :

```
<select class="themeSwitch">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>     
<div id="container"> <!--PAGE GOES HERE --> </div>
```

**CSS** :

```
#container{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

.custom_class_added{
    background:blue !important;
}
```

**JS** :

```
$(document).on("change", ".themeSwitch", function(){
    var theme = $(this).val();
    if(theme=="red"){     
        $("#container").removeClass("custom_class_added");
    }else if(theme=="blue"){
        $("#container").addClass("custom_class_added");
    }
});
```

Now by changing the value of select box, you can simply change the background color by toggling with css class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this pure JavaScript

```
colorOption.onchange = function() {
    var colorValue = option[colorOption.selectedIndex].value;
        template.style.background = colorValue;
        template.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
};
```

[You can use this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thanushcst/u5Lnuzc4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#bluebttn').click(function(){
    $('#container').removeClass().addClass('blue_theme') ;
});
```

Assuming

ID of you blue button is #bluebttn

Name of your blue css class is blue_theme

*Repeat for other colors.*

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if you dont want to add or remove class and just want to change the color.

```
   $('#yourbutton').click(function(){
        $('#container').css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer what the OP was asking, though it does work.